# external-dns in Kubernetes cluster not authorized to list hosted zones error

Tags: kubernetes, external-dns

I have installed external-dns using bitnami helm chart with version 6.10.2.
I have created IAM policy to give permissions to list Route53 hosted zones.

IAM policy

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "route53:ListHostedZones",
                "route53:ListResourceRecordSets"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

IAM policy is also mapped to serviceaccount

```
eksctl get iamserviceaccount --cluster=testcluster --namespace add-ons
NAMESPACE   NAME        ROLE ARN
add-ons     external-dns    arn:aws:iam::442355839237:role/eksctl-testcluster-addon-iamserviceaccount-ad-Role1-6AV1JQ2NPCMO
```

OIDC is already enabled

```
eksctl utils associate-iam-oidc-provider --cluster=testcluster
2022-10-17 14:31:13 [ℹ]  IAM Open ID Connect provider is already associated with cluster "testcluster" in "us-west-2"
```

However I still see the error in external-dns pod that it is unable to list the hosted zones.

```
7T21:24:03Z" level=error msg="records retrieval failed: failed to list hosted zones: AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::442355839237:assumed-role/workers-eks-node-group-20221013233723853600000005/i-0a1b8a914bcff1436 is not authorized to perform: route53:ListHostedZones because no identity-based policy allows the route53:ListHostedZones action\n\tstatus code: 403, request id: a8f86d66-d7af-4bd0-975c-6f99d1134d50"
```

Strangely..it is also showing "User: arn:aws:sts::442355839237:assumed-role/workers-eks-node-group-20221013233723853600000005/i-0a1b8a914bcff1436" workers-eks-node-group in the role name instead of the role arn:aws:iam::442355839237:role/eksctl-testcluster-addon-iamserviceaccount-ad-Role1-6AV1JQ2NPCMO which maps the service account with Route53 permissions.

Any pointers on why it is failing?arn:aws:iam::442355839237:role/eksctl-testcluster-addon-iamserviceaccount-ad-Role1-6AV1JQ2NPCMO

Comment: I have a the same problem exactly! Also a noob to all this. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: yes..I have posted the answer

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this..
changeresourcerecordsets need to be specific with arns of hosted zones instead of "*"

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/aws.md#iam-policy

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "external_dns" {
count = var.create_role && var.attach_external_dns_policy ? 1 : 0
statement {
actions = ["route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"]
resources = var.external_dns_hosted_zone_arns
}
statement {
actions = [
"route53:ListHostedZones",
"route53:ListResourceRecordSets",
]
resources = ["*"]
}
}
```